# Paginated async Component doesn't trigger setup() on route change

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router, vuejs3, vuejs-transition

I have a paginated component. The `async setup()` method is pulling data from an API to populate the page. It works fine when the route is directly loaded, but when I change the route to a different page slug (eg. clicking a router-link), the component is not reloaded and `setup` is not executed again to fetch the new data.

I guess I somehow want to force reloading the component?

This is my `MainApp` component it has the router view and fallback.

```html
<router-view v-slot="{ Component }">
    <Suspense>
        <template #default>
            <component :is="Component" />
        </template>
        <template #fallback>
            loading...
        </template>
    </Suspense>
</router-view>
```

The router looks kinda like that. You see the page component takes a `page_slug`:

```
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "",
    component: MainApp,
    children: [
        {
            name: "page",
            path: "page/:page_slug",
            component: Page,
            props: true,
        },
        // [...]
    ]
  }
```

And this is how my Page component looks like. It uses the `page_slug` to load data from an API which is then used in the template:

```
<template>
    <div> {{ pageData }} </div>
</template>

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Page",
  props: {
    page_slug: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  async setup(props) {

      const pageData = await store.dispatch("getPageData", {
        page_slug: props.page_slug
      });

      return { pageData }
  }
}
```

When I directly open the route, the fallback "loading..." is nicely shown until the data is returned and the component is rendered.
But when I do a route change to another page, then `async setup()` is not executed again. In that case the url in the browser updates, but the data just remains the same.

How can I solve this case? Do I have to force reload the component somehow? Or have an entirely different architecture to the data loading?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple, when trying to create Vue 3 Single File Components (SFCs) in **Composition API** way as shown below:

```js
<template>
  <!--  Your HTML code-->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'ComponentName',
  async setup():{
        // Your code
  }
};
</script>

<style>
/*Your Style Code*/
</style>
```

`<script>`, will **only executes once when the component is first imported**. So, when the data have changed by other component, the component above will **not updated** or in other words not re-created.
To make your component re-created whenever it about to mount, you have to use `<script setup>` which will make sure the code inside **will execute every time an instance of the component is created**, but you need to re-write your script code with few changes in comparison when using `setup()` method, and also you are able to use both of scripts like this:

```js
<script>
// normal <script>, executed in module scope (only once)
runSideEffectOnce()

// declare additional options
export default {
  name: "ComponentName",
  inheritAttrs: false,
  customOptions: {}
}
</script>

<script setup>
// executed in setup() scope (for each instance)
</script>
```

Read this [documentation](https://vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html) carefully to have full idea.